# Not able count Pulses Generated by PLC

Tags: pi-3, python, pigpio, measuring

I am using the below code to capture the pulses and count pulses for a specified interval but the output not as what i expected. For every pulse it  is giving uncertain value.

The pulse i want to count is from a motor that will generate one pulse per rotation.

I am using **Proximity Sensor** for counting rotations.

**CODE**

```
import time

import pigpio

WIND_GPIO=4

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.set_mode(WIND_GPIO, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_pull_up_down(WIND_GPIO, pigpio.PUD_UP)

wind_cb = pi.callback(WIND_GPIO, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE)

old_count = 0

while True:

   time.sleep(5)

   count = wind_cb.tally()
   print("counted {} pulses".format(count - old_count))
   old_count = count

pigpio.stop()
```

I found this code on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=507103

**I want to count pulses for two conditions:**

(i) One for all rotations from the beginning to End of program

(ii) Count Pulse based on other Pin Status Condition for example start counting if PIN A is HIGH.

How to achieve above mentioned condition using PIGPIO module

Comment: Perhaps your motor is too noisy and bouncy.  Increase debouncing time might help.  I usually recommend newbies to use a stupid, simple, time wasting loop to count the pulses, instead of interrupts.  Once you can count using a loop, you can modify the loop program to interrupt program.  It is also a good idea to experiment counting human button pressing pulses, before trying motor pulses.

Comment: like for one pulse given it is increasing the count for uncertain value, is it because of noise or i need to set bouncetime to prevent calling callback multiple times?

Comment: I don't know how you are managing to run that code.  That version of the Python module was deprecated five years ago.  What does `pigs pigpv` report?

Comment: @Lalit Verma, Yes, you might like to check out the below tutorial for newbies. It starts with a loop program example, showing the bouncing problem which causes fake pulse counting. Then it explains how to use the interrupt based/event driven programming approach to solve the problem. (Software debouncing solution is not described in this tutorial though.) https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/ – tlfong01

Comment: @Lalit Verma, software debouncing, however, can be very simple but not very reliable, or very complicated, for sure not for the faint of heart: https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4024981/My-favorite-software-debouncers. This tutorial describes how to cure bouncing and also EMI noise in one go, for your noisy motor. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a long deprecated version of the pigpio Python module.  Where did you find it?

I suggest you download the latest version of pigpio from the Raspbian repositories.

Try this code.

```py
!/usr/bin/env python

import time

import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit(0)

cb = pi.callback(4)

while True:
   print(cb.tally())
   cb.reset_tally()
   time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Yes i changed that pigpio.start and all that before testing tht code... Didnt use deprecated version

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and include clear photos of the connections between the Pi and the sensor.  I have used Hall sensors to count motor shaft rotations and had no problems in the 9k+ RPM region.

Comment: The above is also the one you provided on raspberry pi forums, it gave random count when i tested manuaaly with pins but gave correct count with 1-2 bounce when used with pnp no proximity sensor

Comment: @LalitVerma I have told you what you need to do.  I can provide no further help.

Comment: Updated questiin @joan